# Adding search function to the AlternateID on the Sales Order Line Grid

Tags: acumatica

I want to add a pxselector to the AlternateID field on the Sales Order Line grid to search multiple alternate id's for a single item for the customer identified on the SOHeader.  I added the following code:

```
namespace PX.Objects.SO {  
    public class SOOrderEntry_Extension:PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry> {
        #region Event Handlers
        [PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Merge)]
        [PXSelector(typeof(Search<INItemXRef.alternateID, 
            Where<INItemXRef.inventoryID, Equal<Current<SOLine.inventoryID>>,  
            And<INItemXRef.bAccountID, Equal<Current<SOOrder.customerID>>>>>),  
            typeof(INItemXRef.alternateID),
            typeof(INItemXRef.inventoryID),
            typeof(INItemXRef.bAccountID)
        )]

        public void SOLine_AlternateID_CacheAttributeCacheAttached() {}
        #endregion
    }
}
```

I also deleted the text control from the Transactions grid and re-added it as a selector.

My selector shows up on the AlternateID field on as expected but when the selector is clicked the error `"Error #107: View doesn't exist"`  is displayed. 
This was an example Ruslan from Acumatica went over with us at Framework training last week in Ohio, but I obviously missed a step.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

George, you put a wrong name for your event handler and that causes the error. Try replacing your handler with the code snippet below:

```
[PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Merge)]
[PXSelector(typeof(Search<INItemXRef.alternateID>),
    typeof(INItemXRef.alternateID),
    typeof(INItemXRef.inventoryID),
    typeof(INItemXRef.bAccountID))]
public void SOLine_AlternateID_CacheAttached(PXCache sender)
{
}
```